# zabbix & mointoring Lync 2013

Tags: zabbix

Is someone trying to monitor Lync 2013 using Zabbix? specifically it and check whether the user can properly login. I found way to monitor Lync 2013 Edge Server and Lync 2013 Front End Server.

Regards
Mick

Answer (score 1):

Try following this below:
[Service State Templates - Lync Server 2013 | ZABBIX Forums](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43336)

The user mike@vtg posted templates for Lync 2013